# Docker-compose service with traefik and internal network

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I want to use both `internal` and an external `traefik` network in my container.
Problem: when I define an `internal` network, traefik loses communication with my service.

```
 traefik_webgateway                 internal network
 +----------+          +--------------------------+
 | traefik  |          |   +------+     +-----+   |
 |        +--------------+ | app  |     | api |   |
 |        | |          | | +------+     +-----+   |
 |        | |  proxy   | |                        |
 |        | |          | |  +-----+      +------+ |
 |        | |          | |  |auth |      |worker| |
 |        +--------------+  +-----+      +------+ |
 |          |          |                          |
 +----------+          +--------------------------+
```

docker-compose.traefik.yml:

```
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.4
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - webgateway

networks:
  webgateway:
    driver: bridge
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  proxy:
    networks:
      - internal # <=== this causes traefik point the healthcheck to the 172 IP instead of the 192 IP (see Edit below)
      - traefik
    labels:
      - traefik.http....

  app:
    networks:
      - internal
  api:
    networks:
      - internal
  auth:
    networks:
      - internal
  worker:
    networks:
      - internal

networks:
  internal:
  traefik:
    external: 
      name: traefik_webgateway
```

I don't want my services to use the external `traefik` network because I want my services to be namespaced for my green/blue deployment.

I was wondering why this is happening and if there's a solution.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I obtained the `proxy` container's network:

```
 docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}  {{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <container id>
```

And received 2 IPS:

```
172.18.A.A  192.168.B.B
```

I have a healthcheck that pings /health. On the traefik dashboard:

```
http://172.18.A.A:8000
```

Traefik is unable to communicate with this IP. Sometimes it's able to when it picks the other IP: `192.168.B.B`.

From within the `proxy` container, I'm able to `ping proxy` (it uses the "B" IP)

```
PING proxy (192.168.B.B): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.16.4: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.090 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.16.4: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.16.4: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.065 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.16.4: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.069 ms
```

I am able to ping: `ping 192.168.B.B`
I am unable to ping: `ping 172.18.A.A`

Comment: Traefik sits on the network webgateway, but the proxy doesnt sit on that network. It sits on two networks called internal and traefik, So how do you expect it to be able to talk to the traefik service on the webgateway network

Comment: Thanks for helping Chris, my proxy uses the network "traefik", which is defined at the bottom as an external network with the name "traefik_webgateway". I thought that would link it to traefik's network?

Comment: What do you mean by _traefik loses communication with my service_? Can you check if the `traefik` container can resolve the `proxy` container via DNS? Can you ping `proxy` from the `traefik` container?

Comment: I added some info in the Update in the main post. I am able to `ping proxy` inside the proxy container. Traefik looks like it's using the wrong IP when it's doing the healthcheck.